# How to export an image from Matlab without using toolbox?

Tags: image, matlab

I can import an image using importdata function, but how can i save the image after processing it?
Toolbox usage is prohibited.

Comment: you mean like with imwrite?

Comment: So you're not allowed to use the image processing toolbox?  What about `imwrite` like Benoit suggested?

Answer (score 1):

You would use `imwrite(imageData,filename)`. Documentation can be found [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html).